# read xml file using jquery in an html file

Tags: jquery, xml

I am new to jQuery and am trying to read in an xml file. I have created a simple html file as shown below and in the same directory have an xml file called allTasks.xml.  I see the alert when the document is loaded and I see the second alert 'Here Now'.  However when I try and use the find method I cannot traverse the xml correctly.  Is there a good way to test if I am actually loading the xml file at all?  Also should this work in a html file or should I be using php?

Any help would be greatly received !

```
html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Read XML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Loaded');

         var $myXML;

         $.get('allTasks.xml', function(data) {
            $myXML = data; ;
             }, 'xml');

             alert('Here now ');

             alert($myXML.find("Tasks>Task>TaskId").text());
      });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar ui-bar-b" style="height:50px;">
  </div>      <!-- end of header  -->


  <div data-role="content">
  <div id='names'></div>

  </div>    <!-- end of content  -->


</div> <!-- end of page div -->

</body>
</html>
```

xml

```
<TaskList>
  <Tasks>
    <Task>
      <TaskId>1</TaskId>
      <Name>Name of Task 1</Name>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <TaskId>2</TaskId>
      <Name>Name of Task 2</Name>
    </Task>
  </Tasks>
</TaskList>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `.parseXML()`? [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: Alert or `console.log` your $myXML within the callback function of `$.get`. `$.get` is asynchronous so your last alert will fire earlier that your `$.get` is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('allTasks.xml', function(data) {
    var parsed = $(data);
    alert( parsed.find('Tasks>Task>TaskId').text() );
}
```

Comment: Hi amakhrov - I tried your solution but i still get no result - I am just coding this in an html file and launching it in my browser should I be doing all of this within a web server istalled on my windows machine ?

Comment: if you use exactly the same code, then take into account that ajax request ($.get) for file:// URL's are prohibited by default - so yeah, you need to host it via the local webserver.

But the parsing code works regardless on how you run the web page